# Parse XML with JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, xml, parsing

So, I would like to know how to parse an xml document with JavaScript.

I've got it working in php (view below)

```
<?php
$xmlGmailFeed = file_get_contents("https://gmail_username:gmail_password@mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/");
$unreadMessages = $xmlGmailFeed->fullcount;
echo $unreadMessages;
?>
```

But the only thing with this, is that it's running using the server's IP address and doesnt let users login to their gmail. It pops up saying that there was a suspicious login attempt on their account. So what Id like to know is how I would be able to do the same thing, but run it from the hosts computer. I was thinking javascript to do it? But please let me know if theres a better way!

Edit:

Heres the code that im using..

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom.",
  dataType: "xml",
  crossDomain: true,
  success: parseXml
});

function parseXml(xml)
{
  var results = $(xml).find("fullcount").text();
  alert(results);
}
</script>
```

Here's a screen shot of my problem:

http://cbog.co.nr/SC.php?img=Admin/AE0BCBAA4F532BC69A932E5DDD8F14F2

and you can see for yourself, live at:

http://cbogausch.com/test.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can just use a [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser). jQuery also offers [`.parseXML()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) if you're willing to use it.

Comment: ohhh alright.. thanks a ton!! I'll get looking into this and post the code after I get everything working.

Comment: Heres the code that im using.. 

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom.",
  dataType: "xml",
  crossDomain: true,
  success: parseXml
});
 
function parseXml(xml)
{
  var results = $(xml).find("fullcount").text();
  alert(results);
}
</script>

Here's a screen shot of my problem: http://cbog.co.nr/SC.php?img=Admin/AE0BCBAA4F532BC69A932E5DDD8F14F2

and you can see for yourself at http://cbogausch.com/test.php

Comment: @Chris_Bogausch That is a cross-domain problem.

Comment: I kinda figured.. Any idea how to overcome? I've been trying TONS of things for the last half hour or so..

Comment: @Chris_Bogausch You would have to look into the documentation surrounding that particular feed. I've no experience with it so I can't really say.